# passing an array of items to jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not entirely sure why this is not doing anything when attempting to pass an array of items to a function. Keeping in mind the reason for the for-loop is so i can change the status of the child ctrl to '+' or '-'

> Uncaught TypeError: items[i].removeClass is not a function

```
function SetClosed(state, items){
    console.log('great');
    if (typeof items === "undefined" || items === null) { 
        var root = $(this).parent();
        items = root.children( ".section-content" ); 
    }

    if (state) {
        $.each(items, function(i, obj) {
            var item = items[i];
            var ctrl = item .children(".ctrl");

            item.addClass("isClosed");
            ctrl.html('-');
        });
    }else{
        $.each(items, function(i, obj) {
            var item = items[i];
            var ctrl = item .children(".ctrl");

            item.removeClass("isClosed");
            ctrl.html('-');
        });
    }

    for ( var i in items ){
        console.log( items[i] );
    }
}

SetClosed(true);
```

Comment: It sounds like `item` is a DOMElement, not a jQuery object. Try `$(item).removeClass('isClosed');`

Comment: Why not simple `items.addClass("isClosed");` and `items.removeClass("isClosed");` ? Best solution is `items.toggleClass("isClosed", state);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the result using [.toggleClass( className, state )](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-state)

```
function SetClosed(state, items){
    if (typeof items === "undefined" || items === null) { 
        items = $(this).parent().children( ".section-content" ); 
    }

    //toggle the class
    items.toggleClass("isClosed", state); 

   //Change text of children
    items.children(".ctrl").html(state ? '+' : '-');
}
```

Comment: the reason for the for-loop is so i can go through each child and change its text as well though..

var ctrl = item.children(".ctrl");
ctrl.html('+'); or ctrl.html('-');

Comment: @JokerMartini, You can still achieve it using `items.children(".ctrl").html(state ? '+' : '-');`

Answer (score 1):

You can trim your code (and make it far more readable) if you use `.toggleClass()` instead:

```
function SetClosed(state, $items){
    $items = $items || $(this).parent().children(".section-content");
    $items.toggleClass('isClosed', state);
}
```

Quoting [**the docs**](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/):

> The second version of .toggleClass() uses the second parameter for
>   determining whether the class should be added or removed. If this
>   parameter's value is true, then the class is added; if false, the
>   class is removed.
>
> In essence, the statement:
>
> ```
> $( "#foo" ).toggleClass( className, addOrRemove );
> ```
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> if ( addOrRemove ) {
>     $( "#foo" ).addClass( className );
> } else {
>     $( "#foo" ).removeClass( className );
> }
> ```

This method (as many 'processing' ones) deals with all the elements in `$items` collection, so there's no need to iterate over them manually with `.each`. If you do need some individual action, that can be done on chain:

```
function SetClosed(state, $items){
    $items = $items || $(this).parent().children(".section-content");
    $items.toggleClass('isClosed', state)
          .children('.ctrl').html(state ? '+' : '-');
}
```

... as setter form of `html()` sets the HTML contents of **each** element in the set of matched elements.

Comment: the reason for the for-loop is so i can go through each child and change its text as well though..

var ctrl = item.children(".ctrl");
ctrl.html('+'); or ctrl.html('-');

Comment: Then why did you exclude that from your question? Updating the answer.